How to Calculate the Curl for $\vec{\nabla}\times\hat{a}$ for unit vector $\hat{a}$ in Cartesian, Cylindrical, and Spherical Coordinates
Proving $\vec{\nabla}\times\hat{a}=0$, only for Unit Vector $\hat{a}$ in the Cartesian Coordinate system, but not Cylindrical or Spherical Coordinate Systems
The curl of unit vectors is important in determining the Curl of a Vector,
in arbitrary Curvilinear Coordinates,
namely $\vec\nabla \times \vec D$ in terms of scalar multiplications, applying the triple vector product $\vec D=\left(\vec B \times \vec C\right)=\left(D\hat B \times \hat C\right)$ where $\hat{B}$ and $\hat{C}$ are both unit vectors each of magnitude 1.
In Cartesian Coordinates, for example $\hat{x}=\hat{y}\times\hat{z}$, $\hat{y}=\hat{z}\times\hat{x}$, and $\hat{z}=\hat{x}\times\hat{y}$, that is that for each of the unit vector coordinates, that they can be expressed in terms of cross products of other reciprocal unit vector coordinates in any Curvilinear Coordinate system.
Background Reference
In the article "Proof of orthogonality of unit vectors in orthogonal Curvilinear Coordinate System
See:".  See also,", the question states:

One can either prove

$$\mathbf{u}_i\times\nabla q_i=\mathbf{0}$$ (i.e.; $$\mathbf{u}_i$$ is parallel to $$\nabla q_i$$) so that orthogonality follows from eq. (1),
Or, prove that $$\mathbf{u}_i\cdot\nabla q_j=0$$ for $i\neq j$$


But the answer there does not seem to prove that  $\vec{\nabla}\times\hat{a}=0$, for any Unit Vector $\hat{a}$ for any Curvilinear Coordinate System.
Thus, how can it be proven that $\vec{\nabla}\times\hat{a}=0$, for any Unit Vector $\hat{a}$ for the Cartesian Coordinate System, but not for the Cylindrical and Spherical Coordinate Systems and Actually Calculate $\vec{\nabla}\times\hat{a}=0$ in the Cylindrical and Spherical Coordinate Systems?
Given that in the Cartesian Coordinate System, that:
$$
\vec{\nabla}\times\hat{a_x}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\hat{x} & \hat{y} & \hat{z} \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial}{\partial y} 
  &\frac{\partial}{\partial z} \\
1 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}=\vec{0}
\text{  ,  }
\vec{\nabla}\times\hat{a_y}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\hat{x} & \hat{y} & \hat{z} \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial}{\partial y} 
  &\frac{\partial}{\partial z} \\
0 & 1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}=\vec{0}
\text{  ,  }
\vec{\nabla}\times\hat{a_z}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\hat{x} & \hat{y} & \hat{z} \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial}{\partial y} 
  &\frac{\partial}{\partial z} \\
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}=\vec{0}
$$
Then also any simple rotation that the rotation (direction of the unit vectors) does not depend on the coordinates, also the curl is zero.
Some New Insight
For any unit vector in Curvilinear Coordinates, the magnitude is always 1.  Thus along any path, following the direction of the vector, there cannot be a first-order increase or decrease in the direction of the path of the vector, or else the magnitude of the unit vector would increase or decrease, and the unit vector would no longer be a unit vector.
Quoted from:  "Div, Grad and Curl in Orthogonal Curvilinear Coordinates":




So, if $\Psi=h_1 *u_1 $ then $\vec\nabla \Psi$ has a magnitude of 1.  Further quoted:



Use of the first coordinate $u_1$ only is adequate for the proof.
Further, $\vec{\nabla_1}=\vec{u_1}\left(\vec{u_1}\bullet\vec\nabla\right)$
and $\vec{\nabla_1}\bullet \vec \nabla \Psi_1=
\frac{\partial}{\partial u_1}\frac1{h_1 u_1}
\left(h_1 u_1\right)=0$ (since the derivative of a constant is zero).
It seems that therefore that if:
$$
\vec\nabla \bullet \hat{\Psi}=0
$$
Then (just like the magnetic potential $\vec A$) that
$$
\hat{\Psi}=\vec\nabla \times \vec A
$$
And (from the vector identity for the divergence) that
$\vec\nabla\times\left( \vec\nabla\times \vec{A} \right)=
\left(
-\left(\nabla \right)^2
+\vec \nabla \left(\vec \nabla \bullet\right)
\right) \vec A$, with the divergence of a unit vector being assumedly being $0$ that (with the Coulomb gauge $\vec\nabla\bullet \vec A
=0$):
$$
\vec\nabla \times \hat{\Psi}=\vec\nabla \times 
\left(\vec\nabla \times \vec A\right)
=-{\nabla}^2 \vec A
$$
But then I am stuck with the proof that the curl of a unit vector in general Curvilinear Coordinates is zero.
It seems that if the Laplacian $\nabla^2$ of the unit vector of the potential $\vec A$ is $\vec 0$, then also the curl
$\vec{\nabla}\times\hat\Psi=\vec 0$.  Is this the necessary and sufficient condition for the curl of a unit vector to be zero?

You can't prove this because it's not true. What is true is that the reciprocal basis of a holonomic basis has no curl. If $p(x^1,x^2,x^3)$ is the function taking coordinates $x^1,x^2,x^3$ to points then $e_i=\frac{\partial p}{\partial x^i}$ is the corresponding holonomic basis. It's reciprocal $e^j$ is defined by $e^j\cdot e_i=\delta^j_i$ and it's easy to compute that $e^j=\nabla x^j$. So now $\nabla\times e^j=0$ for all $j$ because we're taking the curl of a gradient. This has nothing to do with unit vectors, and in fact if you normalize $e^j$ then the curl will be nonzero in general.

@Nicholas Todoroff:  If the magnitude of $e_j$ is 1 and $e^j*e_i=\delta_i^j$ it seems like the magnitude of the two vectors times the cosine of the angle between them is $1$.  Is $e^j$ parallel to $e_i$ and if so, why does the magnitude of $e_i$=1 and the magnitude of $e_i$ times $e^j$=magnitude $\delta_i^j$=$1$ imply that the magnitude of $e^j$ is also $1$?

If you are working with orthogonal coordinates so that $e_i$ is an orthogonal basis, then $e^i$ is parallel to $e_i$ and has magnitude $1/|e_i|$. This is because $e_j\cdot e_i = 0$ if $i \ne j$, and then we need $$1=e^i\cdot e_i = |e^i||e_i|.$$ If the basis $e_i$ is not orthogonal then $e^i$ will not be parallel to $e_i$. In general, $e^i$ is orthogonal to the hyperplane spanned by $e_1,\dotsc,e_{i-1},e_{i+1},\dotsc,e_n$ and will not have unit magnitude even if $e_i$ has unit magnitude.

Or simply $\nabla\times\mathbf{a}=\epsilon_{ijk}\partial_ja_k$. I suppose that Levi-Civita tensors can be used to split the metric basis.
For a general vector coordinate $\mathbf{x}=x\hat{\textbf{e}}_x +y\hat{\textbf{e}}_y +z\hat{\textbf{e}}_z$ ($|\mathbf x|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$):
\begin{align}
&\nabla\cdot\mathbf x=3,\text{ and,}\\
&\nabla\times\mathbf x=\epsilon_{ijk}\partial_jx_k=\hat{\textbf{e}}_x(\partial_yz-\partial_zy)+\hat{\textbf{e}}_y(\partial_zx-\partial_xz)+\hat{\textbf{e}}_z(\partial_xy-\partial_yx)\equiv\mathbf0.
\end{align}
Too long for a comment...
This link might be a good reference.
